# Same SQL Server authentication user, same SQL Server Management Studio, different computers, different query results?

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server with a SQL Server authentication user of `ExampleUser` and `ExamplePassword`. On all of the machines in the plant, we can connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio and run a `Select * from ExampleTable` and see live data up until 5/27 (today). On two machines in the building, when we connect with the same credentials on the same SSMS version and run the exact same query, we only see data up until mid April.

Edit: this was working on the two machines for months/years.

Nightshift experienced errors last night and digging deeper this morning we realize we cannot see live data.

Comment: Where is the data being fed from?

Comment: It's impossible to answer because there's no information in the question, not even the query. SQL Server won't return different results based only on the machine's IP. If there were hardware problems, have a DBA check the database. If you try to just hack it you may end up losing the data and have to restore the database from backup

Comment: I would make sure the problem machines are actually connecting to the same SQL Server instance as the ones that work.

Comment: I'll repeat this, if there were hardware issues, get a DBA. Don't try to "fix" things. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong database. Perhaps the query is used the current date to filter and those machines use the wrong date?

Comment: @ARC postive.  we open ssms, type in the server name and connect on 2 different machines using the same sql authentication user.  both machines see the same databases and tables, but when you look at the data in the tables 1 machine has live data and the other doesn't have anything after mid april

Comment: Does `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;` return the same name?

Comment: @DanGuzman yes it does

Comment: @ARC it does not, one of the machines is returning a mac and the other is returning the incorrect IP address

Comment: @ARC no it is not

Comment: @ARC yup we're looking into it now, this at least narrows the problem down tremendously.  thank you for the help

Comment: @Rick, note that `local_net_address` returns an IP address rather than a MAC address. If you see a hex value, that's an IPV6 address. That might help troubleshooting.

Comment: @ARC we had a backup of the sql server running in the cloud for a month that we forgot about and never turned off, the machines were connecting to the backup server. mystery solved